# I want to create a Scarpy with Tornado. Where the USER can enter the URL to search and get the Result in UI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, scrapy

I am completely new to Python. I learned scrapy few days before only.

I want to create a Scarpy with Tornado or some other Python setup. Where the USER can enter the URL to crawl and get the Result in UI.

I tried scrapyrt where the user gets the result as JSON in UI. But I can't able to use the JSON.

I also tried archnado.
https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/arachnado

But it's old version which is not supporting now. When I tried its throwing lots of errors.

Also tried this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/vi7idvzOgU8

Bitbucket project. It's throwing an error. Can someone please help with this by providing detailed steps to implement.

Comment: *`"Can someone please help with this by providing detailed steps to implement."`* No. Nobody can and will "provide detailed steps to implement". That's what the documentation is for. What you are asking for is to do all your work for you. Also, since you don't already know Tornado, you won't understand what the code does. That means if someone does decide to "help" you out, they'd also have to write a very detailed explanation about the code.

Answer (score 0):

Given you just recently learned Python + Scrapy, it would be best for you to learn more about Python because embedding Scrapy in a web server leverages some Python magic. On the other hand, this kind of question pops up from time to time and it should probably be addressed in some form.

What you have to remember is that Scrapy is built using the [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki) framework so you have to make sure whatever web framework you're using has Twisted integration. Luckily for you, [Tornado integrates well with Twisted](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/twisted.html#tornado.platform.twisted.TornadoReactor).

```
import tornado.platform.twisted
tornado.platform.twisted.install()

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging as scrapy_log_conf
from tornado import ioloop, web
from tornado.log import enable_pretty_logging as enable_tornado_log

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.xpath('span/small/text()').extract_first(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr("href")').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)

class RESTfulInterface(web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        # get url to crawl from user
        crawl_urls = self.get_arguments('crawl_url')
        if len(crawl_urls) == 0:
            self.send_error(400)
            raise web.Finish

        crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()
        #deferred = crawl_runner.crawl(QuotesSpider, start_urls=['http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/'])
        deferred = crawl_runner.crawl(QuotesSpider, start_urls=crawl_urls)
        deferred.addBoth(self.crawl_complete)

    def crawl_complete(self, result):
        """
        Do something meaningful after the crawl is complete, like sending an
        email to all the admins.
        """
        print('CRAWL_COMPLETE')

def main():
    enable_tornado_log()
    scrapy_log_conf({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
    app = web.Application([
        (r'/crawl/?', RESTfulInterface),
    ])
    app.listen(port='8888')
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

main()
```

This snippet will scrape pages from `http://quotes.toscrape.com`. The crawl is initiated when you POST to `/crawl` endpoint.

```
`curl -X POST -F 'crawl_url=http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/' -F 'crawl_url=hello' http://localhost:8888/crawl`
```

Comment: This looks good. But How to do this. Is this the tonado file which need to be run in tornado?. Or scrapy file run in tornado confused. Can you tell me the step?

Comment: And this is where I have to be a bit of a jerk and tell you to learn more about Python, Tornado, Twisted, and Scrapy. The topic is too broad to cover here. I did write a blog post a while ago about [embedding Scrapy in a WSGI app](https://notoriousno.blogspot.com/2017/10/embed-scrapy-in-wsgi-application.html) and I've been meaning to write one using Tornado and Klein for a while. Maybe this weekend I'll write it up but for now checkout the blog post. Self promotion over :D